# Cudafy kernel does not compile

Tags: c#, cuda, cudafy.net

Making my first steps with Cudafy and trying to write a function which will take its thread's location and based on that save some int value into an array element.
My code:

```
[Cudafy]
public static void GenerateRipples(GThread thread, int[] results)
{
  int threadPosInBlockX = thread.threadIdx.x;
  int threadPosInBlockY = thread.threadIdx.y;

  int blockPosInGridX = thread.blockIdx.x;
  int blockPosInGridY = thread.blockIdx.y;

  int gridSizeX = thread.gridDim.x;
  int gridSizeY = thread.gridDim.y;

  int blockSizeX = thread.blockDim.x;
  int blockSizeY = thread.blockDim.y;

  //int threadX = blockSizeX*blockPosInGridX + threadPosInBlockX;

  //if i use only one variable, everything is fine:
  int threadY = blockSizeY;

  //if i add or multiply anything, it cannot compile:
  //int threadY = blockSizeY*blockPosInGridY + threadPosInBlockY;


//  results[gridSizeX*blockSizeX*threadY + threadX] = 255;
}
```

So I cannot calculate the `threadY` here. If I use more than one variable in the calculations, the Cudafy translating class throws an error (`CudafyModule cm = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();` throws a Cudafy.CudafyLanguageException).

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
This is the code which runs the kernel on GPU:

```
public void RunTest2()
{
    GPGPU gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);
    CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();
    gpu.LoadModule(km);

    int size = 20 * 20;
    int[] allPixels = new int[size];

    int[] dev_result = gpu.Allocate<int>(size);

    dim3 blocksInGrid = new dim3(5, 5);
    dim3 threadsPerBlock = new dim3(4, 4);

    gpu.Launch(blocksInGrid, threadsPerBlock).GenerateRipples(dev_result);
    gpu.CopyFromDevice(dev_result, allPixels);

    gpu.FreeAll();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to see how you are launching your kernel, the code above should run just fine. I created a test class that runs just fine and gives you a sample of how to prep the kernel grid/block/threads dimensions.
If you want to see great examples download the Cudafy source code and compile the CudafyExamples project, check out how they prep and use the functionality of CUDAfy.

** Note: I must have smoked something pretty good before I posted the first class, I neglected to verify it didn't generate memory access violations!!

Fixed class below, no violations.

Look up great examples on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=c%23+Cudafy&x=0&y=0&sbo=kw) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+cudafy).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Cudafy;
using Cudafy.Host;
using Cudafy.Translator;

namespace FxKernelTest 
{ 
    public class FxKernTest  
    {
        public GPGPU fxgpu;

        public const int N = 1024 * 64;

        public void ExeTestKernel()
        {
            GPGPU gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, 0);
            eArchitecture arch = gpu.GetArchitecture();
            CudafyModule km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy(arch);

            gpu.LoadModule(km);

            int[] host_results = new int[N];

            // Either assign a new block of memory to hold results on device
            var dev_results = gpu.Allocate<int>(N);
            gpu.Set<int>(dev_results);

            // Or fill your array with values first and then
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) host_results[i] = i * 3;

            // Copy array with ints to device
            //var dev_filled_results = gpu.CopyToDevice(host_results);

            // 64*16 = 1024 threads per block (which is max for sm_30)
            dim3 threadsPerBlock = new dim3(64, 16);    

            // 8*8 = 64 blocks per grid, 1024 threads per block = kernel launched 65536 times
            dim3 blocksPerGrid = new dim3(8, 8); 

            //var threadsPerBlock = 1024; // this will only give you blockDim.x = 1024, .y = 0, .z = 0
            //var blocksPerGrid = 1;      // just for show

            gpu.Launch(blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock, "GenerateRipples", dev_results);

            gpu.CopyFromDevice(dev_results, host_results); 

            // Test our results
            for (int index = 0; index < N; index++)
                if (host_results[index] != index)
                    throw new Exception("Check your indexing math, genius!!!");
        }

        [Cudafy]
        public static void GenerateRipples(GThread thread, int[] results)
        {
            var blockSize = thread.blockDim.x * thread.blockDim.y;

            var offsetToGridY = blockSize * thread.gridDim.x;

            // This took me a few tries, I've never used 4 dimensions into a 1D array beofre :)

            var tid = thread.blockIdx.y * offsetToGridY +       // each Grid Y is 8192 in size
                      thread.blockIdx.x * blockSize +           // each Grid X is 1024 in size
                      thread.threadIdx.y * thread.blockDim.x +  // each Block Y is 64 in size
                      thread.threadIdx.x;                       // index into block


            var threadPosInBlockX = thread.threadIdx.x;

            var threadPosInBlockY = thread.threadIdx.y;

            var blockPosInGridX = thread.blockIdx.x;

            var blockPosInGridY = thread.blockIdx.y;

            var gridSizeX = thread.gridDim.x;

            var gridSizeY = thread.gridDim.y;

            var blockSizeX = thread.blockDim.x;

            var blockSizeY = thread.blockDim.y;

            // this is your code, see how I calculate the actual thread ID above!
            var threadX = blockSizeX * blockPosInGridX + threadPosInBlockX;

            //if i use only one variable, everything is fine:
            var threadY = blockSizeY;

            // this calculates just fine
            threadY = blockSizeY * blockPosInGridY + threadPosInBlockY;

            // hint: use NSight for Visual Studio and look at the NSight output, 
            // it reports access violations and tells you where...

            // if our threadId is within bounds of array size
            // we cause access violation if not
            // (class constants are automatically passed to kernels)
            if (tid < N)
                results[tid] = tid;

        }

    }
}
```

> ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem ptxas info    : Compiling entry function
>   'GenerateRipples' for 'sm_30' ptxas info    : Function properties for
>   GenerateRipples
>       0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 328 bytes cmem[0]

Comment: I ran the code above and it simply filled every int[] results with the num 255, but it certainly calculated everything just fine.

Comment: Ok so my indexing wasn't so hot to start, I've never used a four dimensional grid to index into a 1D array before. I added a test to make sure the indexing was correct. Hope it helps, even if it didn't help you it certainly helped me ;)

Comment: I've added the code which runs the kernel (I've made a new project where this now works but in the old project it still does not and I still don't know why)

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you :). I've had those kinds of problems in the past where I have two of the exact same projects, one compiles and runs and can debug, the other simply refuses to compile clean or run. At that point I start cleaning the entire project, manually delete all .cdfy/.cu or temp files from the bin/Debug folder, and go clear the debug symbols cache folder. That hasn't happened to me in a while, but I certainly went through some similar frustrating experiences!
Do me a favor and mark my answer as solved? :D